# Change product data tabs into accordions and move them after the add to cart button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce on the single product page, I am needing to:

- change the default tabs into accordions
- move them up to the right of the main image (after the add to cart button or near there)

Currently, i used [Woo Accordions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-accordions/) plugin to turn the tabs into accordions and it worked great. I also used `functions.php` file to rename and remove tabs. But when i used

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 60 );
```

to move the new accordions-that-used-to-be-tabs, they were tabs again.

I realize this must have to do with the plugin, and i looked at its files somewhat quickly, and there wasn't too much that i wouldn't be comfortable modifying it, but I want to find the best / a better solution before  do that.

Does anyone have any ideas or insight on how i might get those tabs to be accordions in the new location? With or without the plugin i mentioned above that i used.

I am comfortable digging into code in most files, and do already have all of the Woo template files and Avada (my theme) Woo files copied into my Child theme and ready for modification as needed.

If you need me to provide anything else just let me know. There is a screenshot of each - the tabs as accordions in their original location, and then the tabs turned back into tabs when moved up and under the cart button.

[image: tabs made into accordions in original location]
[image: accordions turned back into tabs when moved to where i need them to be]

Comment: If you're able to move the tabs to where you want them, would you be ok with just applying jQuery accordion to them? jQuery UI is included in WP already and you could just hook it into your tabs.

Comment: Hi Tony - that is a great idea and i would definitely love to just uses jQuery! I am going to give it a try and let you know.

Comment: If you need assistance “holla”... I literally just applied it to four different sections of a new site this past week.  (Not WooCommerce though).

Comment: Thanks, I literally just tried it and it worked. After closely comparing the code of Woo's `tabs.php` template and the plugin's corresponding file, I copy and pasted into the Woo template over the Woo code and it worked! I didn't have to recode it but you led me there. (Is adding this as answer best option here?) I once was suspended for not asking questions properly (or something) and am so happy to be back - but want to stay!

Comment: Explain your process with examples and you should be fine; I see nothing wrong with your question and answering yourself isn’t uncommon.  The objective is to have questions with accurate/accepted answers so future users can find them.

Comment: I realized that my last comment is not a great solution, because the code i copied from the plugin's `accordion-tabs.php` file is still relying on CSS and possibly other includes from within the plugin's folders. So  I am still looking. I will take a second deeper look about recoding with jQuery but it might've been not practical.

Comment: What I was suggesting was using the included jQuery UI accordion code which already ships with WordPress - you just have to enqueue it.  You'd then write your own CSS and instantiate it yourself in a js file - wouldn't need to leverage the plugin's CSS or JS at all.